# How to remove translucency that appairs on some parts of a NSTableView?

Tags: xcode, nstableview, macos-sierra, translucency

I'm working on a project for macOS with Storyboards where I have a custom view containing a NSTableView and some other controls.

The customView background is colored in viewWillAppear():

```
backgroundCustomView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
```

The problem is that the items of the NSTableView appears with some translucent parts inside them.

I would like to prefer that the NSTableView appears without any translucency (this is the reason because I put a custom view under the NSTableView).

I tried to change in IB about all what I think could be related options without any luck.

[image]

PS
The discontinued translucency between the items is due by the cell spacing option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specified that you view needs a layer as its backing store

```
backgroundCustomView.wantsLayer = true
backgroundCustomView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
```

More info at `wantsLayer` property documentation [page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1483695-wantslayer)

Comment: Thank you Adolfo, I added the statement but unfortunately the NSTableView continue to show that appearance. Maybe I done something wrong in IB. What I forgot to mention in the question is that the app runs as Status Bar Item and the view opens in the menubar as a NSPopover(). Sorry for the missed info.

Comment: Do the same but now with the main view (NSViewControler's view). Something like self.view.wantsLayer = true

Comment: Thank you so much Adolfo for the info. Also implementing this, I cannot get the transparency to be disabled. I checked this document but it don't seems to be applicable to my situation https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsvisualeffectview

Comment: I dont't know if this is useful, anyway I ust checked this on ViewController: "let a = self.view.allowsVibrancy" and it returns "false".

Comment: Last chance ;) self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor